# Valor semântico da preposição "De"

Tags: preposições

Analisando a seguinte frase, pude notar que o primeiro `de` apresenta um valor semântico de `Máteria`, contudo não consigo saber o valor da segunda frase.

> 1 - Adoro doce de leite
>
> 2 - A menina é um doce de pessoa

Comment: Acredito que existe um `tipo`/`espécie`/`caráter` implícito aqui, junto com uma inversão: "A menina é um tipo doce de pessoa." -> "A menina é uma pessoa de caráter doce". Assim como poderia ser "Ele é um monstro de pessoa." -> "Ele é uma pessoa monstruosa."

Comment: Concordo, faz sentido! Sobre o primeiro valor ser sobre `Matéria`, isso está certo?

Comment: Acredito que sim. Mas no momento não tenho certeza sobre como classificar o caso (2), inclusive por isso só fiz um comentário ao invés de postar uma resposta.

Comment: Bom, vamos esperar outras opiniões, eu agradeço a sua, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As preposições são **palavras funcionais**.  "de" em locuções como doce de leite desempenha uma função de adjetivo quando não existe um adjetivo em si.

Se diz "doce de pessoa" porque, primeiro, o adjetivo pessoal não funcionaria. E na verdade, uma doce de pessoa é uma pessoa doce. E doce é uma pessoa.

O Aulete revela que **um amor é um doce na linguagem popular** quer dizer:

1 Pop. **Pessoa ou coisa muito bonita, graciosa; um encanto; um doce**.
2 Pessoa muito gentil, bondosa, simpática; um doce.

Claro, é preciso dizer: **doce de pessoa** para **distingui-lo** de outros verbetes como **doce de leite** ou **doce de coco** e para o ouvinte ou leitor saber que se trata de uma pessoa e **não de algo que se come.**

Existe leiteiro: vacas leiteiras, rebanhos leiteiros, ou seja, que **produzem leite**. Um alimento feito com ou de leite, se diz: de leite porque não existe um adjetivo que se possa usar.

Outro exemplo: Dizemos um anel de oro, por exemplo. E não anel **aurífero**, porque um anel não produz ouro. **Minas** podem ser **aurífera**s porque produzem ouro.

O "de" é usado para criar uma [locução adjetiva](https://www.mundovestibular.com.br/articles/2446/1/LOCUCAO-ADJETIVA/Paacutegina1.html) na qual a palavra sucedente ao "de" significa "feito de" [algo] ou relativo a [algo].

> Definição formal: "É o agrupamento de duas ou mais palavras que, ao
>   modificar substantivou ou pronome substantivo, exerce o papel próprio
>   de adjetivo. Em geral, a locução adjetiva resulta do encontro de
>   preposição e substantivo (como em teor de açúcar, expressão de
>   macaco), ou preposição e advérbio (como em cardápio de hoje, pneus de
>   trás)."
>
> "Muitas locuções adjetivas equivalem a adjetivos eruditos, que
>   significam "relativo a", "próprio de", "da cor de", "semelhante a"."

Resposta (encurtada) à pregunta: a pessoa é um doce de pessoa, porque não é um doce de leite e porque "doce pessoal" (pessoal sendo um adjetivo ligado a palavra pessoa) seria uma barbaridade a não ser em algum uso bárbaro ou literato.

Comment: Existe o adjetivo "lácteo", "bebidas lácteas" e um alimento feito de leite é um "laticínio".  Mas, em um contexto informal, é melhor dizer mesmo "de leite" do que "lácteo".

Comment: Sim, pode-se dar o exemplo de láctea em vez de leiteiro. Doce lácteo não se diz,né? Seria bom colocar o arroba. Só vi o comentário por acaso.

Comment: Não há necessidade de colocar @ quando estamos escrevendo para quem postou a pergunta ou a resposta.  Vai aparecer um aviso para vc mesmo que eu não escreva Lambie.